# React native: xcode no such file or directory: libreact.a

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I set up a project in React-Native with react-native init , and open iOS project in Xcode. whenever I tried to build, got the same error

```
 no such file or directory: '/Users/vipinjoshi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-eopkvbaiswfqmvgpwpyfvelrgrsk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a'
```

I can't understand what is wrong with the project. I have updated node, watchman, and react-native versions. My Xcode version is 9.2

what I tried:

1) clean and build
2) Clear Derived data

Comment: I am having the same problem when trying to actually deploy to a physical phone.